# Nodejs get data from array of links and save into mongodb

Tags: node.js, request

I need to get some data from list off links and save to Mongodb.

This is my array of link's, that can be from 3 to 10 link's.

```
const links = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4']
```

I'm make request like this:

```
async function fetchAll() {
    let i = 0;
    const results = await Promise.all(links
        .map(
            (url) => {
                return request({
                    uri: url,
                    method: 'GET',
                    json: true,
                }, function (error, response, body) {
                    if(!error) {
                        generateItems(body).then((dt) => {
                            saveItemsToDB(dt).then((rp) => {
                                i++
                                if (i === links.length) {
                                    console.log('last request')
                                }
                            })
                        })

                    } else {
                        i++;
                        console.log(i, ' error')
                    }
                })
            }
        ))
}

async function generateItems(response) {//parse response & generate data}
async function saveItemsToDB(items) {//saving data to mongodb}
```

I have to be sure that the data was saved into Mongodb and after that run next request.

**But the next request runing before the saveItemsToDB function finished**

Comment: use a for loop with async await?

Comment: @cmgchess, so what I need to use?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move request to separate function which returns a promise (you should migrate to `axios/fetch`, `request` is deprecated for some time now), and then call each function and wait until it's finished with `async/await`, and then move to another and pass it required data (you should also process errors with `try/catch`):

```
const links = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4']

async function fetchAll() {

    for (const [i, link] of Object.entries(links)) {

        console.log(+i+1 === links.length ? 'last' : '', 'request', +i+1, link);
        
        const body = await makeRequest(url).catch(err=>throw err);
        const dt = await generateItems(body).catch(err=>throw err);
        const rp = await saveItemsToDB(dt).catch(err=>throw err);

    }
}


function makeRequest(url) {
    // migrate to axios or fetch
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({
            uri: url,
            method: 'GET',
            json: true,
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error) {
                resolve(body);
            } else {
                reject(error);
                console.log(url, ' error')
            }
        })
    });
}
async function generateItems(response) { //parse response & generate data}
async function saveItemsToDB(items) { //saving data to mongodb}
```